# PlayFramework 2.1.1: ClassNotFound in production

Tags: playframework, playframework-2.1

I'm developing a Play 2.1.1 app, without any problem in dev mode (aka with the `run` command, and even with the `start`). The problem comes when I use the `dist` command, to put it in production. I can deploy the app without problems, but when I try to make any request an `ClassNotFoundException` rises.

```
MacBook-:myproject-1.0-SNAPSHOT Marcos$ sh start
play server process ID is 6003
[info] play - Application started (Prod)
[info] play - Listening for HTTP on /0:0:0:0:0:0:0:0:9000
[error] play - Cannot invoke the action, eventually got an error:        Java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: controllers.Application
[error] application -

! @6eo9pbl4f - Internal server error, for (GET) [/venuesList] ->

play.api.Application$$anon$1: Execution exception[[ClassNotFoundException: controllers.Application]]
    at play.api.Application$class.handleError(Application.scala:289) ~[play.play_2.10-2.1.1.jar:2.1.1]
    at play.api.DefaultApplication.handleError(Application.scala:383) [play.play_2.10-2.1.1.jar:2.1.1]
    at play.core.server.netty.PlayDefaultUpstreamHandler$$anonfun$handleAction$1$4$$anonfun$apply$28.apply(PlayDefaultUpstreamHandler.scala:403) [play.play_2.10-2.1.1.jar:2.1.1]
    at play.core.server.netty.PlayDefaultUpstreamHandler$$anonfun$handleAction$1$4$$anonfun$apply$28.apply(PlayDefaultUpstreamHandler.scala:403) [play.play_2.10-2.1.1.jar:2.1.1]
    at scala.Option.map(Option.scala:145) [org.scala-lang.scala-library-2.10.0.jar:na]
    at play.core.server.netty.PlayDefaultUpstreamHandler$$anonfun$handleAction$1$4.apply(PlayDefaultUpstreamHandler.scala:403) [play.play_2.10-2.1.1.jar:2.1.1]
java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: controllers.Application
    at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:366) ~[na:1.7.0_21]
    at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:355) ~[na:1.7.0_21]
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method) ~[na:1.7.0_21]
    at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:354) ~[na:1.7.0_21]
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:423) ~[na:1.7.0_21]
    at sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader.loadClass(Launcher.java:308) ~[na:1.7.0_21]
```

It doesn't work with any "get" or "post".
Any Ideas?

EDIT: I tried the production version in the same development enviroment (same machine, same OS, same Play installation). I obtained the same error. Full stack trace included.

Comment: Can you post anything else from your log file? Full stack trace? Code example(s)? Environment configuration differences?

Comment: Thank you Netizen. I added some more info.

Comment: Do you use a production configuration file to override default configuation in application.conf?

Comment: No I don't. Should I?